# How to group navigation items in the admin panel

Tags: custom-post-types, plugin-development, admin, admin-menu, pods-framework

I have more than 50 custom post types which I have created using the Pods plugin.

The problem is that the left navigation of the admin panel looks really busy and messy and it takes a lot of time for me to get to the needed CPT.

Lots of the CPTs are related to each other, so it would be much cleaner if I created top-level navigation items that includes multiple CPTs.

I've looked for any plugin that does this and I didn't find anything. Can you please recommend a plugin that does this, or if there is a way to use WordPress hooks to code this functionality?

Please keep in mind that the default navigation of WordPress consists of two levels, and I need them to be 3.

The default state is that the second level is a menu that appears when you hover over the parent item. And when they are 3 levels in the updated version, the 3rd level also will need to be a menu that appears when you hover over the 2nd level menu item. The 1st level in the 3 levels menu doesn't need to be hyperlinked.

Comment: I've fiddled with [this one](https://wordpress.org/plugins/admin-menu-editor/) before, but even it restricts you to one sub-menu - 2 Levels

Comment: Where should the 3rd level be? Answer in an [edit] please.

Comment: I just added a paragraph with more explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is very easy with post types generated by Pods. If you create a Custom Post Type with Pods, you can add this to Parent Menu ID: "edit.php?post_type=top_level_post_type"

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is not so easy with post types generated by a plugin.  If you manually create them you can add this:

```
'show_ui' => true, 
'show_in_menu' => 'edit.php?post_type=top_level_post_type'
```

Within the register_post_type argument list to specify where you want them to appear.  You should write to the plugin author and request this feature.